# Why does iteration go on forever when I perform a parametric survival model using streg on Stata?

Tags: stata

On Stata, I want to maximize three different models for the same dataset, i.e. exponential, Weilbull, and Gompertz.

The first two models worked fine with the codes:

```
streg [varlist], dist(exponential)    

streg [varlist], dist(weibull)
```

However, when I ran the third model with `dist(gompertz)`, the iteration process ran on forever when it was fitting the full model (fitting the constant-only model works just fine with just 4 iterations) until number 160 or something, so that I had to break.

At around iteration 20, I think the program has already found the ML point:

> Iteration 16:  log likelihood =  708.13826  (backed up)
>
> Iteration 17:  log likelihood =  708.13862  (backed up)
>
> Iteration 18:  log likelihood =  708.13864  (backed up)
>
> Iteration 19:  log likelihood =  708.13864  (backed up)
>
> Iteration 20:  log likelihood =  708.13865  (backed up)
>
> Iteration 21:  log likelihood =  708.13865  (backed up)
>
> Iteration 22:  log likelihood =  708.13865  (backed up)
>
> Iteration 23:  log likelihood =  708.13865  (backed up)

But it wouldn't stop there at all but went on forever and would never give me the regression result.

I did a few research on the Internet but couldn't find any solution to my problem.

Comment: Hill-climbing algorithms can get stuck on a plateau or a flat ridge. Perhaps one or more of those models is not a good fit for your data. Not a deep answer at all, but we don't have the data to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the iterate(#) option to set a limit of iterations and force your model to stop.
Replace # to the max number of iterations you want to.
Considering the example you gave, you may try using iterate(20)